# Help in solving the differential equation $y'(x)=y(x) + \int_0^1ydx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y(x)$ satisfies the eqn $$y'(x)=y(x) + \int_0^1ydx$$
Where $$y(0)=1$$
Then what will be the value of $$y(ln\frac{11-3e}{2})$$ 
I tried differentiataing both sides wrt $x$, I got
$$y''(x)= y'(x)$$
So $$ y(x)=c $$
So $c=1$ but then I get the wrong answer.

Comment: How do you conclude that $y(x) = c$ from $y''(x) = y'(x)$? That's wrong.

Comment: $y''=y'$ does not imply $y$ is constant. For example, $y=e^x$ satisfies $y''=y'$.

Comment: Oh yeah, so how to continue?

Comment: Also, please look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849488/solving-differential-equation-of-third-degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\int_0^1 ydx$ ,  then $y'=y+a$ which will give $y(x)=ce^x-a$

Now $y(0)=1$, so $c=a+1$ . So $y=(a+1)e^x-a$

Now $a=\int_0^1 ydx=\int_0^1 ([a+1]e^x-a)dx=(a+1)(e-1)-a$ . So from this equation $a=\frac{e-1}{3-e}$. Now put the value of $a$ in the expression of $y$ and get the exact function $y$

Hope this will be helpful !

Comment: It's correct, but how did you get $y(x) = ce^x - a$?

Comment: $y'-y=a$ . It's a first order linear differetial equation. multiply by the integrating factor $e^-x$ and then integrate. you will get this equation.

Answer (score 2):

The integral is a constant, lets call it $c_0$.

Then: $$y'=y+c_0.$$ This has the homogenous solution $y_h=c_1e^{x}$ (solve $y'=y$) and the particular solution $y_p=-c_0$ (assume $y_p=K=const.$ and plug this into the ODE solve for $K$).

So the general solution is $$y(x)=y_h+y_p=c_1e^x-c_0.$$

Now use the initial condition $y(0)=1$.
$$y(0)=1=c_1-c_0$$

Hence, $c_1=1+c_0$. This lead to $$y(x)=e^x+c_0(e^x-1).$$ Now integrate this function from $0$ to $1$ to get the value of and equate this to $c_0$ to determin the value of $c_0$.